# Rethinkdb replication and data consistency

Tags: replication, rethinkdb

What happens when one of the replicas dies temporary/permanently and how does it relate with data consistency?

For example let's consider this situation:
I made an update of a document inside `fruits` table,
rethinkdb answered me with ok and then immediately meteor hits this database

But luckily I had a cluster configured with the following requirements met:
http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/failover/

But it looks like in this scenario I lose this one particular update and probably something else that has not been replicated yet, while application still thinks the data is reliably saved...

I'm not quite understand how I should design my application in order to make it tolerant to such behavior, it seems to be incredible complex

What is a common practice?
Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RethinkDB doesn't acknowledge a write before it has propagated to a majority of the table's replicas. So unless more than one server fail at the same time (assuming you have 3 replicas overall), you will never lose a write that has been confirmed.

The only exception is if you explicitly set the `write_acks` on the table to `"single"`. You can find more details of this setting and its consequences in http://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/consistency/

Answer (score 0):

Consistency in a clustered environment needs a **consensus** algorithm, and the one behind the scenes of RetihnkDB is **RAFT**. RAFT consensus algorithm needs at least 3 nodes to consider strong-ish consistency in your data.

You can read the first blog post

https://rethinkdb.com/blog/2.1-release/